# Three.js & Dreamoc

Tags: three.js

I want to know if there's a template or dimensions to know to use Three.js with the Dreamoc devices.

I found something quite similar :
http://www.instructables.com/id/Reflective-Prism/step3/Four-Sided/
But after looking the display mode of the Dreamoc, the views seems to be placed in a specific way:
[image: Full display]

And after zooming:
[image: Zoom display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a reflective prism example can be found in the three.js dev r.74 branch:

`examples/webgl_effects_peppersghost.html`.

Pull request: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7527

three.js r.73